# How can I use javascript library such as moment.js in react native

Tags: react-native

What is the recommended way to use native javascript libraries in react native? Are there any specific restrictions?

Answer (score 115):

Easy peasy! From the root of your project just run:

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then you can import it in your code:

```
import moment from 'moment';
var now = moment().format();
```

The restrictions would be anything that tries to "reach out" to the browser (which doesn't exist in this context). That's why there's polyfills for things like XHR.

The [official documentation](https://momentjs.com/) has examples on how to use the moment library

Comment: It doesn't look like this actually works.  The same thing with lodash.  Some things work, like the flux package, and some don't.

Comment: I've tried it with moment and it definitely does work. What appears to be the specific problem?

Comment: Have you tried others, like lodash?  It's not working for either for me.  The exported module from `require('lodash')` is an empty object.  I've tried 'lodash-node' as well.

Comment: Looks like others are reporting the same thing: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/406

Comment: Just my 2 cents on the loadash issue, and I'm a noob so don't take my word for it, but in React Native some lib's require OS-dependent code ie in xcode or android. I don't know enough on that yet to comment further. Another thought is that Import statements look in the node_modules folder by default, regardless of package.json. It's also possible that your import statement could be wrong. You might also try variarions:      
import { func } from 'lib'    
or   
import * from 'lib'

Comment: This worked for me.
react-native -v:    
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.50.4

Answer (score 13):

Some of the moment methods work in React Native and others don't. I suspect it has to do with listeners.

I can use moment for formatting:

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")
```

But not for active formatting:

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss").fromNow()
```

Answer (score 7):

to use a npm library just use this command with the respective library name

```
npm install moment --save
```

eg.) npm install {your library name here} --save

then just import in your class and use

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Answer (score 6):

**If you specifically want to use moment.js in react or react native, have a look at `react-moment`, a react component for the moment library, at https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment.**

To use react-moment in react native, run:

```
npm install --save moment react-moment
```

Then in the file you want to use moment:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';
```

Finally, use it as desired, for example:

```
<Moment element={Text} fromNow>
    { post.datePublished }
</Moment>
```

The prop `element={Text}` is specifically for react native. It ensures that the resulting string is rendered in a `Text` component. Without this, react native would throw an error.

Comment: `element={Text}` this thing solved my error .Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like as of right now, some [npm modules are not compatible with the packager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/406).  Haven't really dug into why yet, but what I've been resorting to doing is having a vendor folder and copying over the web version but at the top specifically putting

`/**
 * @providesModule moment
 */`

And at the bottom changing it up to:

`module.exports = moment;`

Not sure if this is the correct way yet, but the packaging is still pretty new to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Install moment.js using the following command,

```
npm install moment
```

Import moment.js in the component

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Moment.js example for calculating the difference between two dates in days.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';

export default function App() {
  const getDifference = () => {
     let date1 = moment("2022-10-30");
     let date2 = moment("2022-12-30");
     let days = date1.diff(date2, 'days')
     return days 
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Days: {()=> getDifference()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```