# Javascript Date().getTimezoneOffset() to use iphone setting timezone instead of physical timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, react-native, timezone

"new Date().getTimezoneOffset()" seems always return physical location time offset, no matter what your device timezone setting is.

For example, if I am in Seattle 9am, iphone timezone setting is auto.  iPhone shows correct time at 9am, and getTimezoneOffset() returns 420.
Changing iphone timezone to manual, Montreal, phone time becomes 12pm.  However, getTimezoneOffset() still returns 420, while I want to have 240 as in East coast time.

I want to test timezone handling.  How do I achieve that (by not actually flying to Montreal)?

(edited to clarify)
With iPhone timezone set to Toronto (offset -04:00),

> moment().utcOffset()

returns real device timezone -420, not in timezone setting -240.

(edited 2)
Note that I want to get iPhone timezone settings, not to hard-coded a specific timezone by string.

Comment: have you tried the same using Moment.js library? here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295846/how-can-i-use-javascript-library-such-as-moment-js-in-react-native

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I tried 
    const minOffset = moment().tz('America/Seattle').utcOffset() - moment().utcOffset();
and got 0 offset.

Comment: This is probably an iPhone specific thing. Some browsers don't read the system timezone except once on startup. Try killing the browser and restarting it after changing the setting.

Comment: Also, `America/Seattle` is not a valid IANA time zone identifier, and you don't need moment-timezone for local-time functionality.

Comment: @MattJohnson Sorry I didn't mention, it's actually react-native code that runs on an iPhone.  No browser.  I Tried restarting the app, same result.  And you're right about the timezone, no America/Seattle, it should be America/Vancouver but I can't edit now.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: @oiman so now are you getting the correct timezone?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal No, although iPhone is set to Toronto (offset -04:00), both moment().tz('America/Vancouver').utcOffset() and moment().utcOffset() return -420.  I want to somehow get -240.

Comment: It would just be the second one. It should just work, so should `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`. Just keep in mind that it would be the *current* offset, which includes daylight saving time. You'll get different values depending on when you run it. However, you should indeed see a drastic change switching to Toronto time.

Comment: well... it's currently the moment().utcOffset() didn't work as expected...

Comment: @oiman You said "No browser". What happens if you do indeed run new Date().getTimezoneOffset() in a browser? Same behavior as your app?

Comment: check this one https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem -- it's the cached timezone data.  To reset it, do:

```
moment.tz.guess(true)  // ignore cache and detect it again
```

then,

```
moment().utcOffset()
```

is correct now.