# why Momentjs doesn't work with React Native?

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to use momentjs with React Native '0.66.4'. Did yarn add moment as usual but still get but keep getting undefined when I try to use moment(). Has anyone had this resolved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use javascript library such as moment.js in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295846/how-can-i-use-javascript-library-such-as-moment-js-in-react-native)

Comment: Maybe you're missing the import statement before using it in your component